# How do we plot a 3D numpy array or a 3D DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I've got a 3D numpy array with elements being 0 or 1. What I need is to plot the array with the indices as the coordinates (x,y,z) and the colour of the point depending upon if the value contained in the element is 0 or 1.
I'm not very great at matplotlib or anything, so looking for recommendations.

Comment: You may want to look at Matplotlib's [mplot3d](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html) or at [Mayavi](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.